# How to downgrade vapor 4 to vapor 3?

Tags: vapor, server-side-swift

I have just downloaded vapor for the first time and I got vapor 4, and unfortunately, all the tutorials I have are built on vapor 3, how to downgrade vapor version?

Comment: Would be better to find me `iMike#3049` in Discord and I’ll help with Vapor 4 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently did this - I think all I had to do was:

```
brew uninstall vapor
brew tap vapor/tap
brew install vapor/tap/vapor3
```

but then I had some unrelated issues with homebrew that took a while to resolve, so I might be forgetting something.

and small side note but make sure to use vapor3 in all terminal commands after this! i.e. even to check if the install was successful - use `vapor3 --help`. I tried `vapor --help` immediately after to check, and thought the install wasn't successful, but actually if `vapor --help` returns an error and `vapor3 --help` works, that is further confirmation the uninstall of vapor 4 worked and you only have vapor3 installed. Similarly, `vapor3 --version`